# Spring data jpa creates wrong fields in empty database for entity with composite primary key that contains foreign key

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

I have following database structure to simplify:

```
Table Product:
-----
id(pk)

Table Place:
-----
id(pk)

Table WarehouseProduct:
-----
place(pk, fk)
product(pk, fk)
count
```

And i use this code to describe database in code:

Place:

```
@Entity 
public class Place {
    @Id
    String id;
}
```

Product:

```
@Entity 
public class Product {
    @Id
    String id;
}
```

primary key for WarehouseProduct:

```
@Embeddable
public class WarehouseProductPK implements Serializable {
    String place;
    String product;
}
```

WarehouseProduct:

```
@Entity
public class WarehouseProduct {
    @EmbeddedId;
    WarehouseProductPK pk;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Product.class)
    Product product;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Place.class)
    Place place;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    int count;
}
```

I test this on empty h2 database. In result is created following table for WarehouseProduct:

```
Table WarehouseProduct:
-----
place(pk)
product(pk)
count
placeId(fk)
productId(fk)
```

How to create required db structure with data jpa in empty database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With following code for WarehouseProduct entity data jpa creates required database structure:

Primary key for WarehouseProduct:

```
@Embeddable
public class WarehouseProductPK implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Place.class)
    Place place;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Product.class)
    Product product;
}
```

WarehouseProduct:

```
@Entity
public class WarehouseProduct {
    @EmbeddedId;
    WarehouseProductPK pk;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    int count;
}
```

In result i got such table for WarehouseProduct in empty h2 db:

```
Table WarehouseProduct:
-----
placeId(pk, fk)
productId(pk, fk)
count
```

Comment: It is inconvenient to use such a complex identifier. Try to get `WarehouseProduct ` by id from the repository. You have to create `WarehouseProductPK ` containing `Place` and `Product`. So you have to get them before.

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi i think that it's not big problem because i can write get method in repository with custom query to get `WarehouseProduct` by `placeId` and `productId`.

`select wp from WarehouseProduct wp where wp.warehouseProductPK.product.id=:productId and wp.warehouseProductPK.place.id=:placeId`
I agree that it doesn't look the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Embeddable
public class WarehouseProductPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="place")
    String placeId;

    @Column(name="product")
    String productId;
}

@Entity
public class WarehouseProduct {
    @EmbeddedId;
    WarehouseProductPK pk;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId("placeId")
    @JoinColumn(name="place")
    Place place;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId("productId")
    @JoinColumn(name="product")
    Product product;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    int count;
}
```

Comment: With this classes application fails to start, because can't load ApplicationContext caused by `org.hibernate.MappingException: cyclic dependency in derived identities`